# is there error on Moldau (=Vltava) arranged for piano by Lechner on measure 59 ? What is the fix?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

In this score of Moldau (called also Vltava), by Smetana, arranged for piano by Lothar Lechner (edition Schott),
is the last note of left hand of measure 59 correct ?

Should it be a C instead of a B ?

[image: "Moldau" (arr. Lechner), mm. 58–61]

Comment: Isn't this from Ma vlast by Smetana?

Comment: @JimM : thank you. I made the fix on the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The note is, correctly, a D. It comes from the second violin and is part of a G major harmony.

[image: "Moldau", m. 59, Violin II, Violas]
(Image source: [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Vltava%2C_JB_1:112%2F2_(Smetana%2C_Bed%C5%99ich)), Boosey & Hawkes edition, PDF page 11)